# Broaching Subject of Fair Compensation

Tags: compensation

I technically have two positions at my workplace. One which I am paid hourly and conforms fairly to State/Federal laws. The other pays by batch (its making dough).

For every batch of dough I make and process I get paid $35. However it takes me like 4-4.5 hours. Which makes it to where I am being compensated under minimum wage. When I get faster I will be making well more per hour. However that will take time, focus, and dedication to achieve.

A friend of mine at work is advocating I just work hard get better. Then I will start making money at it. Another friend who has a similar opinion to me says it shouldn't matter. I should be fairly compensated to do the task. If I am not I should just stick to the hourly paid tasks. What should I do?

Comment: How long does it take the experienced staff to make a batch?  Do they get paid the same amount per batch?

Comment: Would be good if you listed a location, in the US for example I believe 1 that you are still subject to the minimum wage (which does have a training wage time period).  1 = IANAL (I Am Not A Lawyer, and this is a legal issue).

Comment: It will matter a lot how fast experienced workers can produce, and if you think you could physically achieve that and maintain it. While on the upside minimum wage law could insist you be paid at least the minimum per hour, it wouldn't protect you from being fired for being "too slow/poor performance" (especially in the US). If its done in such a way that many people work many hours to produce a piece rate that's too low, and you don't urgently need the job, going to a lawyer who might be interested in such multi-party suit might work. If its just a week or two, unlikely to be worth it.

Answer (score 4):

Like all piece work, you're being compensated against an acceptable rate of manufacture.

If you perform under that rate, you don't get paid so much.  If you work to a faster rate while maintaining the acceptable quality standard, then you get paid more.

You can't expect to be paid the same amount for working less hard than is expected.

Watch some "super fast worker" videos on YouTube, get motivated, get paid more.

Comment: Yeah but that would mean getting the process down to three hours. When it is the task that pretty much keeps our restaurant vok. B

Comment: Going*. I think that merits that it should be compensated a little more fairly especially considering the physical strains that come along with it. I am not being an ingrate but for a specialized task...

Comment: I think "less hard" should be changed to something like "less efficiently" or "less productively" as I think that is what was intended. Somebody could work extremely hard to accomplish a task in 5 hours that someone who is very efficient can complete in 2.

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to be paid for more than the value of your work?

Don't we all?

So, you say you want "fair compensation".  What would be fair?  If you want minimum wage now, when you are not producing, would that same wage be fair if your speed goes up to 1 batch per hour?

What is fair, is whatever you agree to.  If you cannot accept this lower rate of pay as a training wage, then you should seek other employment or negotiate a flat wage.  If you have no confidence in yourself, the flat wage would be the way to go.  If you don't want a flat wage, but want the better money that will come, you have to endure the lower pay at this time.

Those are your options.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your country is, but in the United States, you still have to be paid [minimum wage per hour for piece work](https://www.nfib.com/content/legal-compliance/legal/what-employers-need-to-know-about-paying-piece-rate-74647/).

Your manager should expect that as a new employee, you won't be able to make dough as fast as more experienced employees. But it's his responsibility to pay you at least minimum wage regardless of how fast you work.

Bring the subject up and ask that you be paid at least minimum wage for the piece work.